# Jenkins is running selenium script on headless firefox browser

Tags: jenkins, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am setting up jenkins foy my selenium scripts and when I am running the 
    jenkins, It is running the script on headless browser.
When I am running mvn test command on local , it opens the browser and start the scripts. 
But on jenkins, It just show the below console without launching a browser

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
1554541558637   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\rust_mozprofile.T3HA3HnEMbw5"
1554541560097   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1554541560097   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1554541560097   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1554541567733   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 58226
[Child 56144, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1554038299/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341
1554541568018   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Apr 06, 2019 2:36:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.171 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 20.523 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-06T14:36:12+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Are you running jenkins on docker or Linux VM machine?

Answer (score 0):

When running Automation suite on Jenkin, it would not launch Browser physically. Jenkin execute tests in headless mode. You may not be able to see the results on Browser.